# Learn enumerative combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, self-learning, education

I am interested in becoming proficient in enumerative combinatorics relatively quickly. I want to be able to look at a problem briefly and think of multiple different useful approaches to it. Any advice as to where I should start?

Comment: To "look at a problem briefly and think of multiple different useful approaches to it" is what a Ph.D. is for. That being said, some places to start: Harris' Combinatorics and Graph Theory, Diestel's Graph Theory, Godsil's Algebraic Graph Theory, and I believe Knuth has a good book on Combinatorics, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Combinatorics is much too large, and notoriously ill-defined, to really provide any useful answer to you without knowing your end goal in more detail.  Assuming you want to know enumerative techniques ( I think what most non-experts usually call combinatorics refers to this ), you'll definitely want to get a copy of stanley's Enumerative combinatorics, at the very least volume one, regardless of the type of combinatorics you're interested in.  If you're more interested in computer science applications, then Knuth's books might be better ( but I still recommend Stanley's books ).

Comment: http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf -- is this the one you are referring to?

Comment: Looks like it, yep.  Note that the exercises are arguably the more important part of that book ( the exposition is really good, too, though )